# Is there a way to make the native `browse` button on a file input larger cross browser?

Tags: css, file-io

As you may know, you can make your own file input control using the (hacky) approach of positioning the file input over your custom button and using `opacity: 0` on the file input itself.

The image below shows the intended design with the file input absolutely positioned over the browse button.

[image: Example]

As you can see, the faux browse button is much larger than the one the browser (Firefox 4) has drawn.

If I increase the width of the input, it seems to reach a limit where it won't increase anymore.

[Here is a jsFiddle to play with](http://jsfiddle.net/rH5SY/), demonstrating the problem. The *real* browse button should be the same size as the faux one.

Is there a way to pull this off, or *must* I use Flash or make the button smaller?

Comment: I messed with it a little. It works in Chrome and IE. Does not seem to work in FireFox 4 :(. But this method uses a label. http://jsfiddle.net/rH5SY/3/ <br> The idea was to create a fake browse button but triggers the real one which is hidden.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
font-size:70px;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rH5SY/9/