# HTML Custom Upload Button with hand cursor on hover?

Tags: html, css, file-upload

Following the CSS style trick from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6461252/custom-upload-button) I was able to create a custom upload button. Now, the challenge is to make the entire portion of the button change the mouse pointer icon to the hand one.

The way I partially achieved this can be seen [here (jSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/agilius/gN2JM/). As you can see, the cursor only appears to be a hand while hovering the right area of the the button (I'm in the latest version of firefox).

The css [(also on jSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/agilius/gN2JM/)

```
 <span id="uploadMask">
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" name="file" id="file_upload">
     <span class="button">Select Documents</span>
 </span>
```

The css [(also on jSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/agilius/gN2JM/)

```
#uploadMask {
  width:160px;
  display: block;
  float:left;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:32px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  position: relative;
}

#uploadMask input {
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom: 0;
  right:0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#uploadMask .button {
  background:#ccc;
  line-height:24px;
  padding:5px 15px;
  display:block;
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing you can do it seems to get the `cursor` property to work on the "text" portion of `<input type="file">`, but the "button" part does display the hand pointer.

http://jsfiddle.net/gN2JM/17/

[image]

<sup>**No hand cursor on the red part!**</sup>

Borrowing from the solution to this question:

[Is there a way to make the native `browse` button on a file input larger cross browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487611/is-there-a-way-to-make-the-native-browse-button-on-a-file-input-larger-cross-b)

You can enlarge the button size by adding:

```
#uploadMask input {
    font-size:200px; /* Any high number to guarantee it's big enough,
                        overflow:hidden on the parent takes care of the rest */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gN2JM/15/

Comment: Wow, the font-size little hack is just what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you take off the `opacity: 0;`, you'll see why there is a place where the `cursor:pointer` doesn't show up. [**http://jsfiddle.net/gN2JM/13/**](http://jsfiddle.net/gN2JM/13/) Whenever you are moused over the actual button, it gives the regular cursor.

Use [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1537223/change-cursor-type-on-input-type-file/8667296#8667296)  for a solution that supposedly works all the time, or just set the position of the button to go off the edge of the screen>> [**http://jsfiddle.net/gN2JM/14/**](http://jsfiddle.net/gN2JM/11/)

Comment: Thanks, the javascript solution seems legit :) but the font-size one is easier.